# Capybara how to test for the disabled option in a dropdown list

Tags: cucumber, capybara

I am new to Capybara and am trying to write a test where the default option in a dropdown list will change depending on the link the user clicks on in the preceding page. e.g. click on link1, then link1 will be the default option.

I found online someone said to test for the disabled option in a dropdown with the following, but I still can't get it to work.

```
Then /^"([^"]*)" should be selected for "([^"]*)"(?: within "([^\"]*)")?$/ do |value, field, selector|
  with_scope(selector) do
    field_labeled(field).find(:xpath, ".//option[@selected = 'selected'][text() = '#{value}']").should be_present
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on your description I'm assuming you mean the `selected` option rather than the `disabled` option.  To do that in Capybara would be

```
expect(page).to have_select('id, name, placeholder or label text of select', selected: 'text of selected option')
```

Using that in your cucumber step with the possibility of scoping would then become

```
Then /^"([^"]*)" should be selected for "([^"]*)"(?: within "([^\"]*)")?$/ do |value, field, selector|
  within(selector) do
    expect(page).to have_select(field, selected: value)
  end
end
```

which you would call something like.

```
Then "California" should be selected for "State" within "#user_profile"
```

If you did really want to check for a disabled option in a select you could do it like

```
select = find(:select, 'id, name, placeholder or label text of select') 
expect(select).to have_selector(:option, 'text of disabled option', disabled: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to test if you have the option disabled.
2. Find the number of elements that disable that area. With the command
   "size".
3. If the result is 1 or 0, you can type this command.

Example:

```
And(/^All segments in this area need to be subject to the product (\d+) see it$/) do
  area=find_by_id('temelGostergeler')
  number=area.all("div#urunTab.caption[style='display: none;']").size

  print "All of       "

      expect(number).to eq 0

  if
    number==1
    number="No product"
  else
    number="There are product"
  end
  p number
end
```

You can synchronize with the expect command if you want.